# Selecting last child of recursive list structure with CSS

Tags: html, css

I Want to select last Element of div.container `<ul>` inside last `<li>` with css.
The ul of nested will goes n level so please suggest to me if it possible with jquery also.

```css
ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Nested Item</li>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Nested Item</li>
                            <li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Nested Item</li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Nested Item</li>
                                            <li>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Nested Item</li>
                                                    <li>Want to select list with css</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[view the image that i want to select with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXHBK.jpg)

Comment: You can insert code like that directy as a snippet or at least formatted as code... no need for an image.

Comment: how could i use snippet

Comment: Just click somewhere in your text where you want to insert it and then click the "insert snippet" icon in the toolbar. Now another window opens where you can insert HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some tricks to make it.

If you are looking for last element then you can use of **:nth-last-child(n)** selector, this matches on every element in the nth child and it doesn't look for type or its parent.

This is achieved as it counts from the last child.

```
.container ul li:nth-last-child(1)
{
    color: red;
    font-size:22px;
}
.container li li {
    color: green;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Look at here:
    [MyFiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunkneworld/wpty1kqz/1/)